# change label text for specific cell of uitableView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have label 'Now Playing' and 'Image' that should be display on selected cell, then as i select other cell the prev selected should be clear now.

Code i have written:

```
func didSelectedRow(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tblMusicPro.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? musicTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    if indexPath == currentIndex {
        cell.lblTagsPro.text = "Now Playing"
        cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 1
    } else {
        cell.lblTagsPro.text = ""
        cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

[image: 'Now Playing' and 'Image' should be display on selected cell, then as i select other cell the prev selected should be clear now.]

Comment: You have to write same in CellFor Row !! **and** reload  data or specific indexpath after you change currentIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the state of object of table cell, but it won't be reflected until table cell reloads. You can either reload the whole tableView or reload only 2 cell which are deselecting and selecting.

**For this,**

Keep a variable in your class to store selected cell index

```
var selectedCell: IndexPath?
```

When you click a cell, store `indexpath` in this variable and reload the cell. say,

```
func selectCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCell = indexPath
    self.tblMusicPro.reloadData()
}
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check if cell is selected or not?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: <cell_identifier>, for: indexPath) as! musicTableViewCell
    if indexPath == selectedCell {
        cell.lblTagsPro.text = "Now Playing"
        cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 1
    } else {
        cell.lblTagsPro.text = ""
        cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 0
    }

    //
    // Rest of your implementation
    //

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro you solved my problem! one thing more i have back and next button which play next and prev songs from the array, how i can mange this on both buttons

Comment: If you just want to play previous/next song from list you can simply increase and decrease index of selectedCell and reload cell. But if you want to play previous song you played it might be different from index (say you are playing 6th song and before this you played 2nd song) in this case you need to store play-list.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions for this.

1. Implement TableView delegate method didDeselectRowAt

   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
2. If you have a custom cell class, specify selection/deselection logic in `setSelected` method in the cell class.

   `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)`
3. Set the label property if you have the previouslySelectedIndexPath. Call this method from `didSelectRowAt` delegate method.

   ```
   func removeNowPlayingText() {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: previouslySelectedIndexPath) as? MusicTableViewCell {
             cell.lblTagsPro.text = ""
             cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 0
        }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For this take one array for store **IndexPath**, then check it at `cellForRowAt` as follow this code, add `IndexPath` into an array when select cell and remove if already exist in an array then reload tableview  cell to update value.

```
var selectedCells:[IndexPath] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tblMusicPro.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? musicTableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        if selectedCells.contains(indexPath) {
            cell.lblTagsPro.text = "Now Playing"
            cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 1
        } else {
            cell.lblTagsPro.text = ""
            cell.imgPlaying.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if selectedCells.contains(indexPath) {
            let getIndex = selectedCells.index(of: indexPath)
            selectedCells.remove(at: getIndex)
        }else{
            selectedCells.append(indexPath)
        }

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: true)

    }
```